# CSS linear gradient angle position

Tags: css, background, gradient, linear-gradients

[image]

I am trying to create an angled background using linear-gradient.

However, I can only work out how to create a white area that goes from the bottom left to the top right.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #ffffff 49.8%, #e0e0e0 50%);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bfq3vv6n/

But, I want the white area to start half way up the left side of the page rather than from the bottom, and then finish where it already is in the top right (see image for how I want it to look)

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Do you wanna show an image of how it should look?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have added an image

Comment: That's perfect. Helps.

Comment: I have answered. Check it out and if good, please do accept.

Comment: Man, does the answer work or look good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to calculate if you set the background size to be double in width.

This way, the center of the gradient will be coherent with the middle point being at the center of the left side:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px green;
  background-image: linear-gradient(153.43deg, white 50%, gray 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right top;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would help?

```css
div {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,e0e0e0+40,e0e0e0+100&0+0,0+39,1+40,1+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(225,225,225,0) 39%, rgba(224,224,224,1) 40%, rgba(224,224,224,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(225,225,225,0) 39%,rgba(224,224,224,1) 40%,rgba(224,224,224,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(225,225,225,0) 39%,rgba(224,224,224,1) 40%,rgba(224,224,224,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#e0e0e0',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I used it with the help of [ColorZilla](http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,e0e0e0+40,e0e0e0+100&0+0,0+39,1+40,1+100). Also, it provides a lot of tools to make it look like what you expect.

**Preview**

[image: preview]